# Arrayformula to find overlaps in date ranges

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In a previous question that can be find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72043420), the following formula to find overlaps in date ranges was kindly provided by [Mr Shane](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14678267/mr-shane):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF(($A1<=$B$1:$B$5)*($B1>=$A$1:$A$5)*($C1=$C$1:$C$5),IF(ROW($A$1:$A$5)=ROW(),"","Row"&ROW($A$1:$A$5)),"")))
```

When dragged down, it's result is (column D):

| # | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/01/2022 | 02/01/2022 | Task1 | Row3 |
| 2 | 01/15/2022 | 02/15/2022 | Task2 |  |
| 3 | 01/29/2022 | 02/03/2022 | Task1 | Row1, Row3 |
| 4 | 01/18/2022 | 02/22/2022 | Task3 |  |
| 5 | 02/02/2022 | 02/15/2022 | Task1 | Row3 |

[Link to the sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GQVxs1iNpnvDTeayQz55KeOBL0V5riDQlp4GwirzwJs/edit?usp=sharing)

The question is: could it be replaced by an arrayformula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## SUGGESTION

Perhaps you can use a ***Custom Google Sheet Function*** (*`=findOverlaps()`*) using a script to mimic the `ARRAYFORMULA` behaviour. You may check this sample script below that you can add as a bound script in your spreadsheet file:

> Follow this [quick guide on how to add a bound script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound#google_sheets_or_docs) in your spreadsheet.

### Custom Function Script

```
function findOverlaps(arr) {
  var res = [];
  var filtered = arr.filter((data,index)=>{
                 return data[2] == arr.map((data)=>{return data[2]}).filter((a, i, aa) => aa.indexOf(a) === i && aa.lastIndexOf(a) !== i) ? data.push((parseInt(index)+1)) : null;
  });

  filtered.map((data,index)=>{
    for(var x=0; x < 2; x++){
      filtered.map((check)=>{
        res.push([arr.map((data)=>{return data[2]}).filter((a, i, aa) => aa.indexOf(a) === i && aa.lastIndexOf(a) !== i).join(''),data[3],dateRangeOverlaps((filtered[parseInt(index)][x]),check[0],check[1], check[3])]);
      });
    }
  });

  res = res.filter((z)=>{return z[0] == 'Task1' && z[2] != 'x' ? z[2] : ''});

  return arr.map((x,index)=>{
    return res.map((look)=>{
      if((parseInt(index)+1) == look[1]){
        return "Row"+look[2];
      }
    }).filter((fn)=>{return fn}).join(', ')
  });

}

function dateRangeOverlaps(currentDateToCheck, startDate, endDate, row) {
    return (currentDateToCheck > startDate && currentDateToCheck < endDate) ? row : 'x'
}
```

### Demonstration

> See this sample: [image]

Comment: Altough I rather a formula, this solution works great. Thanks